Does fibrant replacement functor preserve cofibrations between cofibrant objects?
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a model category. In Hovey's book, a fibrant replacement functor $R\colon \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}_{f}$ is given by applying the functorial factorization on the unique morphism $i\colon X \to *$ for each $X$ (note that $*$ is the terminal object),
$$X \xrightarrow{\alpha(i)} RX \xrightarrow{\beta(i)} *$$
where $i$ is a trivial cofibration (it means both a cofibration and a equivalence in Hovey) and $r$ is a fibration. It also induces morphisms $Rf\colon RX \to RY$ for morpshisms $f\colon X \to Y$ in model category $\mathcal{C}$.
My question is for a cofibration between cofibrant objects $f\colon X \to Y$ (i.e.$f\colon X \to Y$ a cofibration in $\mathcal{C}_{c}$), is its induced morphism
$$Rf\colon RX \to RY$$
in $\mathcal{C}_{cf}$ still a cofibration?

Sometimes, but not always.

@ZhenLin Thank you so much! May I ask are there any "good properties" of fibrant replacement functor? such as preserving homotopy pushout or homotopy coproduct?

Those things are invariant under weak equivalences, are they not??

@ZhenLin Oh! Sorry about that, I asked a stupid question!
